# Cross-compiling rsync on OS X 10.8 (64bit) to 10.7 (32bit)

Tags: xcode, macos, cross-compiling, rsync

I need get `rsync` binary with -iconv parameter (>v3.0.0) to OS X Lion (10.7.5) what doesn't have Xcode installed. (The default rsync on OS X is only archaic v2.6.9)

How to compile it from the sources on another computer running Mountain Lion (10.8.4)?

Tried:

```
export CFLAGS="-arch i386"
./configure
make
```

the compiled rsync run ok on the 10.8.4 but when copied it to 10.7.5 says:

```
$ ./rsync
Illegal instruction: 4
```

not works either:

```
export CFLAGS="-arch i386 -m32"
./configure
make
```

**Can please someone tell me how to cross-compile the rsync v3.0.9 on OS X 10.8 for 10.7?**

My system:

```
$ uname -a
Darwin jonatan.local 12.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.4.0: Wed May  1 17:57:12 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.24.15~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

$ gcc --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
```

target system

```
Darwin panda.local 11.4.2 Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.2: Thu Aug 23 16:26:45 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.32.7~1/RELEASE_I386 i386
```

Or, have anyone compiled rsync-3.0.9 for OS X 10.7.5 for download? ;)

Comment: Just get it from homebrew: `brew install https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/master/rsync.rb`

Comment: rsync 3.0.9 with all patches to support HFS+ specialties is also available with my mlbackup package which you can get at https://maclemon.at/downloads/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found this question: [What is the "Illegal Instruction: 4" error and why does "-mmacosx-version-min=10.x" fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268887/what-is-the-illegal-instruction-4-error-and-why-does-mmacosx-version-min-10)

and the

```
export CFLAGS="-arch i386 -mmacosx-version-min=10.7"
./configure
make
```

works. :)