# Illegal Instruction: 4 for iOS

Tags: ios, compiler-construction

I have currently updated an app and pushed to App Store. After the approval process, it can be downloaded from AppStore.

The issue is, "some" of the users report that they cannot switch on the app, either update or download from scratch.

Some of the devices they use:

- iPod Touch (5th Generation)
- iPhone 5
- iPad 2 ''newly added''

The console log shows like this:

UIKitApplication:{app-identifier} exited abnormally with signal 4: Illegal Instruction: 4

I have also got the crash report like this:

```
Incident Identifier: 1912AA89-01F4-4BFE-8BD8-2D8EB3B4B988
CrashReporter Key:   4e0582bb30455ff2c12665099359dfddd3ec9bab
Hardware Model:      iPod5,1
Process:         'app_name' [551]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/C589BCAA-B833-4708-93CA-CDD2ABCBA38A/'app_name'.app/'app_name'
Identifier:      'app_name'
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-07-16 15:45:42.278 +0800
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000e7f5e2fa
Highlighted Thread:  0
```

I cannot find much information on the Internet related to Illegal Instruction: 4, some of those are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268887/what-is-the-illegal-instruction-4-error-and-why-does-mmacosx-version-min-10) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/iphone-gcc-full/issues/detail?id=6).

They lead me to suspect the case is due to:

compiler issue

1. new CPU
2. like A6 / A6x
3. armv7s

Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: I have the exact same issue here: a friend of mine downloaded the application from AppStore and boom, it crashed during startup. I added his device on my provisioning profile and tested the application from XCode: worked perfectly.

Comment: The case doesn't exist for apps built using xcode.

Comment: The issue came from using Crittercism SDK 4.0.2, for users having set custom accessibility settings.

Comment: Did anyone report it to Crittercism team?

Comment: It's in their release note. I haven't seen any other communication anywhere else. I've engaged them on Tweeter, no answer : https://twitter.com/btoueg/status/378467419485794304 I think they suck.

Answer (score 0):

Apple did not give any comment, after doing the Support request.

We uploaded the new ipa with all the same settings to iTunes Store again, and ask for Expedited Review. Apple approves the app in one day. Then, problem no longer exists.