# Failed to create sdcard in the AVD folder on Mac 10.7.5

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

I'm using Mac OSX 10.7.5 and I recently re-install the newest ADT 23 which version named "adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140624".

I removed the older version of ADT which only support to API 18 (I don't remember what the version code is it...) before install the new one.

While I completed installation, update API to 19 by SDK Manager, but I haven't updated 4.4W and API 20.

I tried to create a new emulator with the setting value on SD Card field, and then press OK.

The console panel would occurred error message:

[2014-07-09 02:44:13 - SDK Manager] Failed to create the SD card.

[2014-07-09 02:44:13 - SDK Manager] Failed to create sdcard in the AVD folder.

With the same creating steps, the problem above haven't displayed in the older version of ADT that I used before.

I tried if I don't set SD card value to create a new emulator, that can be created successfully!

I also tried to install Eclipse 4.4 Luna and the newest SDK package separately, it still has the same problem...

I'm not sure if there's any problem on my OSX or have I missed any steps of settings during installation.

Please kindly give me some suggestions to fix my problem, appreciate!

Comment: By the way, the alternative way that not to face the problem of mine,  to create a emulator that without generate SD card inside. That also can use the ADT version 23 to develop Android App. If you need to develop the App that need SD card to write in or read data inside, please use your Android device to instead of it.

Answer (score 5):

It's been 2 months since you've opened this case, so I hope that you've reached a resolution by now. I've actually experienced the same issue with creating an SD Card on my Mac 10.7.5 OS using the Eclipse ADT Bundle. When I couldn't rely on the GUI, I moved over to using the CLI for creating the sdcard using the mksdcard command located in the sdk/tools folder (ex: mksdcard 64M /tmp/sdcard.img). In doing so, I noticed that I was receiving an Illegal Instruction: 4 error. When tracking this error down further (ex: [What is the "Illegal Instruction: 4" error and why does "-mmacosx-version-min=10.x" fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268887/what-is-the-illegal-instruction-4-error-and-why-does-mmacosx-version-min-10)) I noticed that it's an issue with the way that the mksdcard command was compiled and that my 10.7.5 OS was not capable of executing this command.

Resolution (at least for my case):

1. Backup the mksdcard command in the tools folder. Example cp
   mksdcard mksdcard.bak
2. Download a previous version of the tools that were known to work on the 10.7.5 OS   (http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r22.6.2-macosx.zip)
3. Extract the tool and copy the mksdcard command from the newly extracted folder to your Eclipse/sdk/tools folder (essentially replacing the mksdcard command that we know doesn't work).
4. Restart Eclipse
5. Create a new AVD using the AVD manager and assign a value (ex: 32M) for the sdcard
6. You should no longer see the failed to create sdcard error.

Resolution 2:
Update your Mac to a later version (10.8.x or above). I've tested this and have confirmed that mksdcard is working on later versions of Mac OS X without this issue.

Let me know if this resolves your issue as well.

Comment: From the OP (Deleted Answer) : @IAMSME Changing the mksdcard resolves the same issue also for mac 10.6 series. Thank you for this helpful insight.

Answer (score 2):

You can try run this in shell

cd /Users/MyUserName/Library/Android/sdk/tools/

chmod +x mksdcard

[Android Studio IDE on Mac os:error=13, Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27587227/android-studio-ide-on-mac-oserror-13-permission-denied)

Answer (score 1):

in my case , i just update android Emulator.
SDK Manager -> android sdk -> sdk tools.
update Android Emulator

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a bug in the GUI that's not letting you past the SD card step.  You could try skipping the GUI by using the 'android' command directly.  After experiencing this problem, I was able to create an AVD using this command:

> $ android create avd -t 3 -n TestAVD

This uses a lot of defaults. To see options for '-t',  use 'android list targets'.  Take a look at the options for 'create avd' with this command:

> $ android --help create avd

Hope that helps.