# Android Studio IDE on Mac os:error=13, Permission denied

Tags: android, macos, permissions

I downloaded an Android Studio for Mac and then want to run SDK manager,console then puts the message:

```
 ProcessNotCreatedException: Cannot run program "/Users/MyUserName/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android": error=13, Permission denied
```

OS version:Yosemite 10.10.1

Android Studio version:1.0.1

What is the main cause for such error? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I ran into the same problem today.

And I fixed this by adding executable permission to the file `/sdk/tools/android`

Open your terminal and

```
chmod +x /Users/MyUserName/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android
```

Comment: I fixed with " chmod a+x android"

Answer (score 1):

```
chmod a+x /Users/deva/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator64-arm
chmod a+x /Users/deva/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator
```

I had to do these additionally to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Re-install Android Emulator from SDK Manager > SDK Tools should be back to normal