# Ant build error = exec-shell returned:1

Tags: android, temenos-quantum

I am doing one demo project in Kony Studio. While running application for Android, I always getting `Ant build error`.

Please check the error log,

```
-post-package:
[exec-shell] 
[exec-shell] /Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:1037: The following error occurred while executing this line:-do-debug:
[exec-shell] 
[exec-shell]  [zipalign] Running zip align on final apk...
[exec-shell] /Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:1039: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[exec-shell] /Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:336: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Users/maca/Library/Android/sdk/tools/zipalign" (in directory "/Users/mac/KonySampleApps/temp/DisplayText/build/luaandroid/dist/DisplayText"): error=13, Permission denied
[exec-shell]    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.processException(ProcessBuilder.java:478)
```

Log says there is a permission issue with file, but I gave both read/write permission, even no luck and I am using `MacBookPro`. Help me to come out from this issue. Thanks in advance.

Got solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27587227/android-studio-ide-on-mac-oserror-13-permission-denied) post

Answer (score 0):

Check that `/Users/maca/Library/Android/sdk/tools/zipalign` exist and is executable. Google often moves zipalign (among other tools) around.

If it is missing copy one (the newest) from `/Users/maca/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/…` to `/Users/maca/Library/Android/sdk/tools`.