# AVD fails to boot on Mac "permission denied(13)"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Simply trying to get my android emulator to boot up. However, I keep getting the message ERROR: Resizing partition failed with exit code 1. I have completely uninstalled Androidstudio and reinstalled but nothing changed, still getting the same error. I have also used both Hardware - GLES 2.0 and Software - GLES 2.0 graphic settings in the AVD settings but get errors for both.

I am using a MacBook pro.

Here is the run error and also the errors caught by logCat.

```
ERROR: resizing partition failed with exit code 1
```

This is the error when using Hardware - GLES 2.0

```
 08-09 14:21:07.461 1184-1184/? E/libEGL: load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
    08-09 14:21:07.652 1184-1184/? E/SurfaceFlinger: hwcomposer module not found
    08-09 14:21:07.675 1184-1184/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
    08-09 14:21:08.169 1184-1241/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
    08-09 14:21:08.700 1251-1254/? E/libEGL: load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
    08-09 14:21:08.755 1251-1254/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
```

This is the error when changing to Software - GLES 2.0

```
08-09 16:07:50.886 1184-1184/? E/SurfaceFlinger: hwcomposer module not found
08-09 16:07:50.950 1184-1184/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
08-09 16:07:51.226 1184-1243/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
08-09 16:07:51.890 1252-1254/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-01 00:00:00.000 0-0/? E/Internal: Connection refused
```

Comment: Might be a problem with your GPU, check that you have the latest graphics drivers, if that doesn't work go to your AVD settings and disable "use host GPU"

Comment: Where is "use host GPU"? The only part in the graphics section in the AVD settings allows me to choose Hardware - GLES 2.0 or Software - GLES 2.0.

Comment: They may have changed the name, try setting it to software

Comment: When changing it to software, still get ERROR: Resizing partition failed exit code 1. However, different errors arose in logCat: `08-09 15:59:31.150 1186-1186/? E/SurfaceFlinger: hwcomposer module not found
08-09 15:59:31.186 1186-1186/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
08-09 15:59:31.373 1186-1240/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
08-09 15:59:31.721 1249-1251/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)`

Comment: What's happening on the emulator screen, like is it just stuck at the boot image?

Comment: Yeah it's stuck on the boot image. Also, in androidstudio a window pops up saying AVD failed to load because of the following errors and it gives the partition error.

Comment: I'm pretty much out of ideas. Have you tried to create a new AVD with some basic configuration? maybe have it using a different android version and just play around with the config.

Comment: Yeah I have I'm really not sure why every combination I'm trying does not work.

Comment: The partition error seems somewhat generic according to my searching. Do you have any unusual hardware/software, like are you running Linux/Mac, laptop, older AMD cpu?

Comment: I'm running on a MacBook pro laptop, pretty new. I don't think I have any unusual things installed... And I have never had this emulator problem before

Comment: That might be the secret, check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27596242/1401661

Comment: I tried it but it still did not work

Comment: your issue has been bugging me. I don't use a Mac, is it possible to start Android Studio as root/sudo/admin and see if that changes anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its your GPU settings in your avd setting..probably..is the USE host GPU box checked?

Comment: There is no use host GPU box in the settings, on the option for using hardware or software graphics. Neither one works

Comment: in the avd editing settings for the emulator image you are trying to start..its there trust me