# how to fix mksdcard error on Android Studio Setup on Mac?

Tags: android, macos

How do I fix this error on running the Android Studio setup on Mac OSX10.7.5
"Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool.
One common reason for this failure is missing required libraries
Please fix the underlying issue and retry."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241640/error-unable-to-run-mksdcard-sdk-tool)

Answer (score 6):

The `mksdcard` utility distributed with recent versions of the Android SDK was compiled in a way that it won't run on OS X versions older than 10.8. You can replace your `mksdcard` with an older copy of the utility that's known to work on OS X 10.7.5, such as the one in http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r22.6.2-macosx.zip.

Credit where its due: This solution is from [IAMSME's answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26149680), which I found via googling "illegal instruction 4" after I got that error message when a hunch led me to test `mksdcard` on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Try running a Package Manager (like apt-get or brew, you will likely need brew since you are on Mac OS X) for downloading some additional packages *Android Studio* couldn't install.

**sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6** (Command line for Ubuntu OS)

Apart from setup *Android Studio* should check whether is capable to run 32-bit components like aapt or adb. Hopefully it will serve you as a work around.

BTW this is a Google bug currently being addressed (not sure what *Titanium Studio* has to do here as quoted by Mark previously).

i.e. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=152213

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me was to drag titanium studio into the trash and reinstall it.  I spend hours trying to work this out, but couldn't.  After a reinstall it just worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using an older version of Android Studio until this gets sorted out by Google.