# Error: Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Keep getting an error in the set-up wizard while trying to install android studio on Ubuntu.

```
"Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool."
```

Also, in the terminal I get this:

```
[ 115528]  ERROR - tRunWizard$SetupProgressStep$1 - Android Studio 1.1.0  Build #AI-135.1740770 
[ 115531]  ERROR - tRunWizard$SetupProgressStep$1 - JDK: 1.8.0_40 
[ 115531]  ERROR - tRunWizard$SetupProgressStep$1 - VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
[ 115531]  ERROR - tRunWizard$SetupProgressStep$1 - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
[ 115531]  ERROR - tRunWizard$SetupProgressStep$1 - OS: Linux 
[ 115532]  ERROR - tRunWizard$SetupProgressStep$1 - Last Action:
```

Answer (score 313, accepted):

This really needs to be added to the documentation, which is why I filed [an issue about it](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82711) a few months ago...

You need some 32-bit binaries, and you have a 64-bit OS version (apparently). Try:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
```

That worked for me on Ubuntu 14.10.

**UPDATE 2017-12-16**: The details will vary by Linux distro and version. So for example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31088492/115145) covers newer Ubuntu versions.

Comment: Just in case this isn't common knowledge, I had to reboot for the changes to take effect. Furthermore, I can verify that this command is necessary on Elementary OS Freya (64 bit).

Comment: I am on Freya (14.04) 64 bit and when I try to install it's failing because of some dependency: 

lib32stdc++6 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed

Comment: Tried this on 15.04. It seems the only package you need is lib32stdc++6: `sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6`

Comment: I can't comment on what packages may be needed, but to @JohnP. 's point on a restart being required, this wasn't the case for me (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Comment: in case anyones interested, this also worked for 12.04 after a reboot

Comment: In my experiment, `lib32stdc++6` alone helped me to start the Android Studio successfully. However, later when I tried to build my project I got "aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1". `libz.so.1` is exactly what `lib32z1` provides.

Comment: i had issues with UBUNTU 15. I replaced it with UBUNTU 14 and installed java jdk 7 and ran the command given by commonsware...was able to build successfully...

Comment: Ubuntu 15.10: `Unable to locate package lib32bz2-1.0`

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: you can install libbz2-1.0:i386 instead. The instruction is here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/637113/unable-to-locate-package-lib32bz2-1-0.

Comment: @CommonsWare when I try to install it says **Media change: please insert the disc labeled
 'Ubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.1)'
in the drive '/media/cdrom/'**. how can I solve this?

Comment: This works for Ubuntu 16, but you need to remove lib32bz2-1.0. It's not available through standard apt-get, and apparently isn't needed to fix this issue

Comment: @CommonsWare how to install above libraries in Windows 10? pls help

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia: This question and its answers are focused on Linux, as the error is seen on Linux. If you are having problems with `mksdcard` on Windows 10, I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @CommonsWare  can you please check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47445288/install-32bit-binaries-for-windows-10-fix-issue-cordovalibprocessdebugresourc

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package lib32bz2-1.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'lib32bz2-1.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lib32bz2-1.0'`

Comment: @user924: The exact modules varies by Linux distro. On newer Ubuntu versions, [you do not need `lib32bz2-1.0`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31088492/115145)

Answer (score 248):

For **UBUNTU 15.04,15.10,16.04 LTS, Debian 8 & Debian 9** Try this command:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

Comment: In addition to the above I also needed to add other 32 bit libraries using `sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5 lib32z1 ` because otherwise build fails with the error **Unable to locate package lib32bz2-1.0** I got the hint from this ubuntu answer http://askubuntu.com/a/147409

Comment: Works on Debian 8 as well.

Answer (score 13):

For Ubuntu, you can try:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
```

For Cent OS/RHEL try :

```
sudo yum install zlib.i686 ncurses-libs.i686 bzip2-libs.i686
```

Then, re-install the Android Studio and get success.

Comment: I need to do `sudo dnf install zlib.i686 ncurses-libs.i686 bzip2-libs.i686 glibc.i686 libstdc++.i686` in Fedora 24.

Answer (score 10):

Here's what you need to do to fix the issue on Arch Linux :

1. Enable the `multilib` repository on your system if you have not already done so by uncommenting the `[multilib]` section in `/etc/pacman.conf` :

   ```
   [multilib]
   Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
   ```
2. Update pacman :

   ```
   # pacman -Suy
   ```
3. Install the 32 bit version of libstdc++5 :

   ```
   # pacman -S lib32-libstdc++5
   ```

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 15.04

`sudo aptitude install lib32stdc++6`

Firstly, I installed aptitude, which helps in installing other dependencies too.

Answer (score 5):

if you do this: 
`sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6`. 
You may get this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package lib32bz2-1.0

E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'lib32bz2-1.0'

E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lib32bz2-1.0'
```

So i suggest just doing this:

`sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6`

And also, the AOSP should look for how while installing Android-Studio, that is installed too.

Answer (score 3):

Just to say 16.04, I'm running

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 libbz2-1.0:i386 lib32stdc++6
```

seems to work on a vanilla install after installing oracle-jdk-8

Answer (score 0):

This workaround also works with 15.04 (64bit). Since there isn't (yet?)
lib32bz2-1.0 for vivid:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=lib32bz2-1.0

I installed the one from Utopic.

Comment: @Snippet My install worked by just omitting this package entirely

Answer (score 0):

In case of **lubuntu** 14.04 use

> sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6

P.S-no need to restart the system.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

When I tried the Accepted ans my Android Studio hangs on start-up

This is the link

> http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/linux-32-bit-libraries

and This is the Command

```
$ sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1
```