# "Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool" Install Android Studio, Error

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, debian

I try to install Android Studio but I get "Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool".
I read about this issue here: [32-bit libraries on Linux](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81908) but there are solutions to Ubuntu and I try it but it don't be fine to Debian.

```
root@debian:# uname -a

Linux debian 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u2 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@debian:# dpkg --add-architecture i386
root@debian:# apt-get install libc6:i386 

Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
No se pudieron instalar algunos paquetes. Esto puede significar que
usted pidió una situación imposible o, si está usando la distribución
inestable, que algunos paquetes necesarios no han sido creados o han
sido movidos fuera de Incoming.
La siguiente información puede ayudar a resolver la situación:

Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
 ca-certificates : Depende: openssl (>= 1.0.0) pero no va a instalarse
                   Depende: debconf (>= 0.5) pero no va a instalarse o
                            debconf-2.0
 libc6 : Rompe: libc6:i386 (!= 2.19-11) pero 2.13-38+deb7u8 va a ser instalado
 libc6:i386 : Rompe: libc6 (!= 2.13-38+deb7u8) pero 2.19-11 va a ser instalado
 libcups2 : Depende: libavahi-client3 (>= 0.6.16) pero no va a instalarse
            Depende: libavahi-common3 (>= 0.6.16) pero no va a instalarse
            Depende: libgnutls26 (>= 2.12.17-0) pero no va a instalarse
            Depende: libgssapi-krb5-2 (>= 1.10+dfsg~) pero no va a instalarse
 libkrb5-3 : Depende: libcomerr2 (>= 1.34) pero no va a instalarse
             Depende: libk5crypto3 (>= 1.9+dfsg~beta1) pero no va a instalarse
             Depende: libkeyutils1 (>= 1.5.9) pero no va a instalarse
             Depende: libkrb5support0 (= 1.13~alpha1+dfsg-1) pero no va a instalarse
 libnss3 : Depende: libnspr4 (>= 2:4.9-2~) pero no va a instalarse o
                    libnspr4-0d (>= 4.8.6) pero no va a instalarse
           Depende: libsqlite3-0 (>= 3.5.9) pero no va a instalarse
 tzdata : Depende: debconf (>= 0.5) pero no va a instalarse o
                   debconf-2.0
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generó cortes, esto puede haber sido causado por paquetes retenidos.
```

Sorry about output is in spanish.
Also I try to install manually one by one dependecies but there are more dependencies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool in ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241640/error-unable-to-run-mksdcard-sdk-tool-in-ubuntu)