# Android Studio Installation -Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool. on 32 bit Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: android-studio

So, I am trying to install Android Studio in

> **OS : UBUNTU 12.10, 32 bit**.

And I tried installing it for 3-4 times each time it got stuck due to slow internet connection and showing **Connection Lost** in the terminal.

Now , this time when I again did

> **./studio.sh**

it shows

> **Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool.
>   One common reason for this failure is missing required libraries
>   Please fix the underlying issue and retry.**

I saw various posts which shows this occurs in 64 bit OS and installing libraries using

> **sudo apt-get install ia32-libs**

or

> sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6

will install required 32 bit libraries , but I am already on a 32 bit OS .

and when I try above command , I get

> E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate.

Software center also shows negative result:
[image]

So, the point is has anyone came across this in a 32 bit UBUNTU 12.10 OS .
Any workaround will be greatly appreciated .

**Edit 1**
Output when I try to install mentioned libraries for Ubuntu.

> yogeshwardancharan@ubuntu:~/Android/Sdk/tools$ sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Package lib32bz2-1.0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>   is only available from another source
>
> Package lib32ncurses5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>   is only available from another source
>
> Package lib32stdc++6 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>   is only available from another source
>
> Package lib32z1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>   is only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'lib32z1' has no installation candidate
>   E: Package 'lib32ncurses5' has no installation candidate
>   E: Package 'lib32bz2-1.0' has no installation candidate
>   E: Package 'lib32stdc++6' has no installation candidate

In above output it is mentioned that package may be available from another source ...can someone please help , what that source may be ?

Is it possible to compile these libraries from source . If so , how can I do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes , I already know that 12.10 is no longer supported . It would be great if you can provide a workaround like using some archived repository etc .......I am not sure of this .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool in ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241640/error-unable-to-run-mksdcard-sdk-tool-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me the answer was here http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/linux-32-bit-libraries

At the time of this answer, the required libraries are

```
$ sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1
```

Good luck!

Comment: In most cases, for me also, installing only `libstdc++6:i386` also works.

Comment: Hello @e_m0ney i had this problem while installing m i tried to install by menstioned command in question same error . so i canceled that error than retry now when i open android studio it didn't appear is it okay