# Unable to Run mksdcard sdk tool on ARMv7 Processor Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, android-studio, armv7, crouton-os

When trying to install Android Studio on my Linux Laptop, I get "Unable to Run mksdcard tool" From what I can tell from searching, this is usually caused by lacking the 32 bit compatibility libraries on 64 bit Linux, however I am running it on an ARMv7 processor, using [the crouton project](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton) to use Linux on my Chromebook. I have tried install the recomended packages ending in i386, but the command line returned:

Reading Package Lists... Done
Building Dependendency Tree
Reading State information... Done
E: unable to locate package [Name of package here]
E: Couldn't find any package by Regex '[Name of package]'

Does anyone know what is causing this and how I can fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure this question is clear enough, because to me it reads like you're trying to put 32-bit x86 libraries on a 32-bit ARM Chromebook because of 64-bit... something..., and that makes very little sense whatsoever. Unless possibly you're trying to cross-compile x86 code on an ARM host system for, er, _reasons_, but that's a highly unusual thing to be doing.

Comment: I'm relatively new to linux, So I tried putting in the packages recommended to other users with similar issues in order to fix the error when I try to install android studio, but attempting to do so did not work. Judging by your reaction, I assume that was not the right path to take. I'm mostly trying to get the program to run, moreso than anything else. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: OK, where exactly are you installing Android Studio from? The download from the website is almost certainly a non-starter - if parts of that fail on 64-bit x86 due to missing 32-bit native libraries, that implies they contain 32-bit x86 code, which isn't going to run at all on an ARM machine. Unless you've found a ready-made ARM version, you're probably looking at building it (or at least the native code parts) from source yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool in ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241640/error-unable-to-run-mksdcard-sdk-tool-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

I've discovered a workaround.

After a little searching, I've found that we *can* create executable binary of the tool for the ARMv7 platform ourselves! *Whupee*!

1. Head over to [GitHub](https://github.com/miracle2k/android-platform_sdk/blob/master/emulator/mksdcard/mksdcard.c) and pick up the source code, `mksdcard.c`. Download this to wherever you'd like, but make sure you download it as `mksdcard.c` and not as `mksdcard.c.txt`, which your browser might try to do. You can always rename the file later in case you accidentally save the filename incorrectly.
2. Over in your `chroot` environment, head to the directory where you downloaded the file.
3. Make sure you have the `gcc` compilation tools installed. Try running `gcc -v` in an attempt to see what version of GCC you have installed. If this doesn't work, you'll need to install GCC via `sudo apt-get install gcc`.
4. Run `gcc -o mkdscard mksdcard.c`. This uses GCC to compile the source code into something that can be executed. After compilation has completed, you can use `./mkscard` to have Linux execute the binary file, which verifies that it works.
5. Navigate to your Android SDK Tools directory. This is usually `~/Downloads/Android/Sdk/tools`. By running `ls`, you'll list the files and find the version of `mksdcard` that your Linux distribution doesn't understand how to run. (Running `./mksdcard` on this file will confirm this.)
6. Backup the broken binary somewhere, then delete the copy in the `tools` folder. (I created a `backups/` directory within the Android SDK Tools folder to move it to.)
7. Within the directory, use `rm -r mksdcard` to delete the old `mksdard` binary.
8. Finally, copy your compatible binary over to take it's place, e.g. `cp ~/Downloads/mksdcard .` (Copies the `mksdcard` binary we've created to the current directory `.`, the Android SDK Tools folder.)
9. Head back over to your Android Studio installer. In the dialogue complaining about `mksdcard` failing, hit **Retry** and the installation should continue. After it's finished, be sure to apply any updates that are recommended by the environment. Enjoy!

Comment: Environment: CentOS7. I am following the procedure as advised above. Renamed the original executable mksdcard to mksdcard.txt. Downloaded, placed mksdcard.c in ../sdk/tools/ and compiled using "gcc -o mkdscard mksdcard.c". It created executable binary mksdcard. But, getting exception bashc: .: mksdcard: cannot execute binary file.  Please guide me!

Answer (score 1):

For newer versions eg. 3.1 C4 of Android Studio running with Ubuntu on ARM32 you will also need to place *mksdcard* in ~/Downloads/Android/Sdk/**emulator** (referencing like path from Alext T.).