# Android Studio install failed - unable to run mksdcard sdk tool in Windows

Tags: android, sdk

I installed Android Studio, but now fail in installing Android SDK when start lauching it. 
It says "unable to run mksdcard sdk tool", and tips that some libraries may be missing.
I tried 32bit and 64bit but resulted the same.
jdk: 1.7.0_80
os: windows 7
what should I do now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool in ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241640/error-unable-to-run-mksdcard-sdk-tool-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Not a duplicate, this is on a different OS, though similar issue.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, some SDK tools such as `mksdcard.exe` require Microsoft Visual C++ runtime 2015-2019. Some download links can be found here.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Answer (score 2):

According to Subaru answer,some SDK tools such as mksdcard.exe require Microsoft Visual C++ runtime. 
So go to your System properties and check your System type:

[image]

Then based on your system type,(for me it was x64) download/update the latest Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2019 from the link https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

[image]

After installing Microsoft Visual C++, my problem was fixed.
All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install or update latest version of visual c++. I have solved same issue by update visual c++.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ click on other tools and framework  then locate Microsoft visual c++ redistributable for visual studio 2019 and download