# Unable to run mksdcard.exe SDK tool android v3.5.2 at windows10

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I'm facing this issue while installing android studio components.
Android v3.5.2
windows 10

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqiDm.png)

Comment: have you tired hitting "show details" when it is installing? maybe there will be more specific info in there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio install failed - unable to run mksdcard sdk tool in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35496486/android-studio-install-failed-unable-to-run-mksdcard-sdk-tool-in-windows)

Answer (score 3):

I faced this error while installing android studio. The below steps fixed my issue.

Go to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads & Install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019. and then continue the Android studio installation.

Choose the appropriate installation file for your OS.

x86: vc_redist.x86.exe

x64: vc_redist.x64.exe

Comment: Can you provide me the full steps?

Answer (score 1):

This could be because of some missing c++ dependency libraries. Please try installing the vc++ 2015 -2019 runtime from the below link and try again:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Comment: can you provide me the full steps to resolve this issue?