# Android Studio ':app:mergeDebugResources' FAILED

Tags: android

I just installed Android Studio, made a project and when the project was building I got this error in the gardle console:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
Error: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command '/home/krisitown/Programming/SDK/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt''
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command '/home/krisitown/Programming/SDK/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt''

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.585 secs
```

The only thing I did was change the

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```

in the dependencies because it was giving me an error, after some google-ing I came to the conclusion that it was giving me an error because in the previous line I had a plus sign (+) for the version

EDIT: Here is my build.gardle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Have 2 of em:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.firstapp.krisitown.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 15
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

Comment: put your build.gradle

Comment: where you change compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'

Comment: You may also wish to clean your project (Build > Clean Project from the Android Studio main menu) to see if that helps.

Comment: tried cleaning the project but it stays the same

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so apparently the issue was caused by the fact that I was running a 64-bit Ubuntu OS and I needed some extra packages, so in case anyone wonders here is the mystical line solver of this situation:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
```

I found the answer here, so props to the guy who answered it:
[Error: Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241640/errorunable-to-run-mksdcard-sdk-tool-in-ubuntu)