# I'm getting "unable to run mksdcard sdk tool" with Android Studio

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to follow [Install Android Studio | Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html) (Instructions for Linux) and I'm getting following error:

```
(trusty)alexus@localhost:~/Downloads/android-studio$ sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
[sudo] password for alexus: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package lib32z1
E: Unable to locate package lib32ncurses5
E: Unable to locate package lib32bz2-1.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lib32bz2-1.0'
E: Unable to locate package lib32stdc++6
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lib32stdc++6'
(trusty)alexus@localhost:~/Downloads/android-studio$
```

My environment:

```
(trusty)alexus@localhost:~/Downloads/android-studio$ uname -a
Linux localhost 3.14.0 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jul 6 21:45:00 PDT 2016 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
(trusty)alexus@localhost:~/Downloads/android-studio$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS"
(trusty)alexus@localhost:~/Downloads/android-studio$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.4 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
(trusty)alexus@localhost:~/Downloads/android-studio$
```

Please advise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241640/error-unable-to-run-mksdcard-sdk-tool)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libz1:i386 libncurses5:i386 libbz2-1.0:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Adding a little commentary to your answer would improve it. Would you please [edit] it and add some explanation? Thank you!