# Unable to run Android Studio on Ubuntu (WSL2)

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio, wsl-2, android-sdk-2.3

I have one WSL2 Ubuntu where I installed Android Studio in 2 different ways, with the same error. I need to work with flutter.

1st way: [I followed this tutorial](https://addshore.com/2022/01/installing-android-studio-on-wsl2-for-flutter/)

2nd way:

```
sudo snap install android-studio --classic
```

The error I receive when I try to run android-studio is this:

> CompileCommand: exclude com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot.trieDescend bool exclude = true
>
> Start Failed
> Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues
>
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /snap/android-studio/127/android-studio/jbr/lib/libawt_xawt.so: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:388)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:232)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:174)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2389)
> at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:755)
> at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1953)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:388)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:232)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:174)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.findFromPaths(NativeLibraries.java:315)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:285)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2398)
> at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:818)
> at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1989)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1388)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1386)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1385)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.initStatic(Toolkit.java:1428)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1397)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Color.<clinit>(Color.java:277)
> at com.intellij.ide.ui.laf.IdeaLaf.<clinit>(IdeaLaf.java:24)
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
> at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil$preloadLafClasses$1.invokeSuspend(StartupUtil.kt:579)
> at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
> Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Toolkit
> at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil$initAwtToolkit$1$1.invokeSuspend(StartupUtil.kt:485)
> at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
> 4 more
> Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Toolkit
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(EventQueue.java:1332)
> at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.RawSwingDispatcher.dispatch(RawSwingDispatcher.kt:15)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:322)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:30)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable$default(Cancellable.kt:25)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:110)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:126)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(Builders.common.kt:56)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(Unknown Source)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch$default(Builders.common.kt:47)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch$default(Unknown Source)
> at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil$updateFrameClassAndWindowIconAndPreloadSystemFonts$1.invokeSuspend(StartupUtil.kt:686)
> at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
> 4 more
>
> ---
>
> Your JRE: 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231 amd64 (JetBrains s.r.o.)
> /snap/android-studio/127/android-studio/jbr
>
> Also, a UI exception occurred on an attempt to show the above message
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Toolkit
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:632)
> at com.intellij.idea.StartupErrorReporter.showMessage(StartupErrorReporter.java:85)
> at com.intellij.idea.StartupErrorReporter.showMessage(StartupErrorReporter.java:39)
> at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.kt:65)

The error I receive when I run `flutter doctor` is this:
[image: Flutter Doctor Error]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241640/error-unable-to-run-mksdcard-sdk-tool)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve it with help from ChatGPT!

It was mainly about missing dependencies.

1. Install the library libXrender to communicate with Windows

```
sudo apt-get install libxrender1
```

2. Then I modified the file `~/.bashrc` adding in the last line the content

```
export DISPLAY=:0
export XAUTHORITY=$HOME/.Xauthority
```

3. Then I ran the command

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then I received a new error...
4) Then I used `sudo apt-get install` to install the libraries `libxtst6` and `libxi6`

And then it finally worked!