# How do i get Genymotion not to crash on start in OSX?

Tags: macos, crash, genymotion

My Genymotion hasn't been opening since i updated it a few weeks ago. I'm on OSX 10.11.5.  From what i can skim from the apple crash log is its saying "Illegal instruction: 4" and according to [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14269066/5162742) its a generic problem with my binaries.

I have uninstalled multiple times, and read Genymotion's docs for removing, and reinstalled the .apps from thier latest version, but it still crashes. Even reinstalled virtualbox to see if that would help.

So i think the problem is with apple or with some settings file that was not documented that stayed behind and keeps messing it up.

Does anyone know of how i can completely remove everything Genymotion related so i can do a fresh clean install?

This has been ongoing for a few weeks now and i have not heard anything back from their support. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

See [this Question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38167803/genymotion-crash-on-start-in-osx), which has the same issue.

No solutions yet, but install the [2.6.0](http://files2.genymotion.com/genymotion/genymotion-2.6.0/genymotion-2.6.0.dmg) this still works.

Comment: Thank you, installing the old version seemed to work.  Hopefully a new version will come out with a fix, till then, thanks :)

Comment: Problem is, that the old 2.6.0 has different images and in the download section of Genymotion 2.6.0 only the actual 2.7.2 images are shown which are maybe not 100% compatible :(
I already had deleted my 2.6.0 images unfortunately, when trying to completely uninstall Genymotion. This was a mistake.

Comment: Genymotion 2.8.1 does work again. But still it is extremley slow and therefore unusable :(