# Genymotion crash on start in OSX

Tags: macos, genymotion

I'm use Mac OS El Capitan 10.11.5

Installed VirtualBox 5.0.24

Genymotion 2.7.2

And when i'm starting Genymotion i get crash -- see image:-
[image: geny error]

text from crash report

```
Process:               genymotion [1051]
Path:                  /Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/genymotion
Identifier:            com.yourcompany.genymotion
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           genymotion [1051]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-07-03 10:38:17.680 +0300
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.5 (15F34)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        890BAC95-7988-7846-0ECE-0DEC8BFB2C9E

Sleep/Wake UUID:       10886C01-28E6-49CC-B63D-2AA32EEC3A87

Time Awake Since Boot: 6500 seconds
Time Since Wake:       3700 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib           0x0000000103f1e758 lh_new + 196
1   libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib           0x0000000103e70467 OBJ_NAME_init + 48
2   libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib           0x0000000103e70780 OBJ_NAME_add + 34
3   libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib           0x0000000103f27f3f EVP_add_cipher + 42
4   libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib           0x0000000103f2b9cd OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers + 19
5   libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib           0x0000000103f2b9b4 OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf + 14
6   com.yourcompany.genymotion      0x0000000103cde27c 0x103bf6000 + 950908
7   com.yourcompany.genymotion      0x0000000103c9011a 0x103bf6000 + 631066
8   com.yourcompany.genymotion      0x0000000103c975bb 0x103bf6000 + 660923
9   com.yourcompany.genymotion      0x0000000103c871d5 0x103bf6000 + 594389
10  com.yourcompany.genymotion      0x0000000103ca47f6 0x103bf6000 + 714742
11  com.yourcompany.genymotion      0x0000000103c04277 0x103bf6000 + 57975
12  com.yourcompany.genymotion      0x0000000103bfc324 0x103bf6000 + 25380
13  com.yourcompany.genymotion      0x0000000103bfbf84 0x103bf6000 + 24452

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8865befa kevent_qos + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90cfe165 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 216
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff90cfddcd _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8865b5e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff981c1578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff981bf341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8865b5e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff981c1578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff981bf341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8865b5e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff981c1578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff981bf341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8865b5e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff981c1578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff981bf341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8865b5e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff981c1578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff981bf341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8865b5e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff981c1578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff981bf341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 8:

Thread 9:: Qt bearer thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8865ad3e __pselect + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff88658274 pselect$1050 + 82
2   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x0000000104f09cc8 qt_safe_select(int, fd_set*, fd_set*, fd_set*, timespec const*) + 104
3   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x0000000104f0ad80 QEventDispatcherUNIXPrivate::doSelect(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>, timespec*) + 672
4   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x0000000104f0be4a QEventDispatcherUNIX::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 234
5   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x0000000104eb637d QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 381
6   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x0000000104cac4d5 QThread::exec() + 117
7   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x0000000104caff63 0x104c7b000 + 216931
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff981c199d _pthread_body + 131
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff981c191a _pthread_start + 168
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff981bf351 thread_start + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000103e70488  rbx: 0x00007f91c951f880  rcx: 0x000000000000000f  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000107b58a00  rsi: 0x00007f91c9500000  rbp: 0x00007fff5c009340  rsp: 0x00007fff5c009320
   r8: 0x0000000000000007   r9: 0x00000000fffffe00  r10: 0x0000000000000012  r11: 0x00007f91c9500000
  r12: 0x0000000103f88cf2  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000103e70488  r15: 0x0000000103e704d5
  rip: 0x0000000103f1e758  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x00000001050518a0

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x0200018a
Trap Number:     133
```

if start from terminal i get next text

```
    iMac-Alex-Neo:~ alexneo$ /Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/genymotion ; exit;
Logging activities to file: /Users/alexneo/.Genymobile/genymotion.log
Illegal instruction: 4
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
Deleting expired sessions...none found.

[Process completed]
```

Comment: I have the same problem and it is quite frustrating.

Comment: Same issue running Genymotion 2.7.2 on Mac OS Yosemite 10.10.5 on an Intel Core 2 Duo 3.06 Ghz machine with 8 GB RAM and VBox 5.0.24. Stumbled into a wall learning Android and its really frustrating.

Comment: Same here, OS 10.11.5, Genymotion 2.7.2 with VirtualBox 5.0.24
Genymotion 2.6.0 works. Is this bug solved? (by the way, Genymotion is super slow on Mac, on PC it is very much faster)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just figured out how to force Genymotion **2.7.2** to work on OS X.

You should have **Genymotion 2.7.2** and **homebrew** installed.

```
brew install openssl
```

or if you have it already installed

```
brew upgrade openssl
brew cleanup
```

**remember**: find returns a list (old homebrew packages will be included), so if you have several homebrew openssl versions you should skip third command (cp `find` stage) and copy openssl dylib manually

Fix for: **Genymotion.app**

```
cd /Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/Frameworks  
mv libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib.bak
sudo cp `find /usr/local/Cellar/openssl -name libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib` /Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/Frameworks/
```

Fix for: **Genymotion Shell.app**

```
cd /Applications/Genymotion\ Shell.app/Contents/Frameworks
mv libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib.bak
sudo cp `find /usr/local/Cellar/openssl -name libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib` /Applications/Genymotion\ Shell.app/Contents/Frameworks/
```

**P.S.**: It seems that libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib in Genymotion **2.7.0 - 2.7.2** was built for Sandy Bridge or newer CPU's and crashing on instruction 
**vxorps %xmm0, %xmm0, %xmm0**

**EDIT:**
missed commands to update embedded player.app (genymotion VM tool), but we need to update it too... if we want to run VM's ;-)

Fix for: **player.app**

```
cd /Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/player.app/Contents/Frameworks  
mv libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib.bak
sudo cp `find /usr/local/Cellar/openssl -name libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib` /Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/player.app/Contents/Frameworks/
```

Now Genymotion **2.7.2** works

Answer (score 2):

Upd. I downgrade to version 2.6.0, and that fix this problem.

Comment: Could you please post the link to download the 2.6.0 Genymotion version (.dmg)? Thanks!

Comment: [Genymotion 2.6.0](http://files2.genymotion.com/genymotion/genymotion-2.6.0/genymotion-2.6.0.dmg)

Comment: It seems all the direct links to 2.6.0 on Genymotion's site are now redirecting to the 2.7.2 download page. @suprandr's link to [download 2.6.0 via CNET](http://download.cnet.com/Genymotion/3000-18513_4-76475942.html) does still work, though.

I can also confirm downgrading to 2.6.0 solves the "crash on launch" problem on Mac.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that Genymotion 2.6.0 works on a Mac that presents this problem. Download [link](http://download.cnet.com/Genymotion/3000-18513_4-76475942.html)

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm this with OS 10.11.5, Genymotion [2.7.0](http://files2.genymotion.com/genymotion/genymotion-2.7.0/genymotion-2.7.0.dmg) or [2.7.1](http://files2.genymotion.com/genymotion/genymotion-2.7.1/genymotion-2.7.1.dmg) or the actual 2.7.2 using the actual VirtualBox 5.0.24

I even [uninstalled Genymotion totally](https://www.genymotion.com/faq/#genymotion-uninstall)
like told in the FAQ, doing this:

```
rm $HOME/.Genymobile/genymotion*
rm -rf $HOME/.Genymobile/Genymotion
rm -rf "~/Library/Preferences/com.genymobile.genymotion.plist" "~/Library/Saved Application State/com.genymobile.genymotion.savedState"
killall -u $USER cfprefsd
```

But no change. All three versions 2.7.0, 2.7.1 and 2.7.2 are not working, because they crash immediately at start, even with a previous clean uninstall.

[Genymotion 2.6.0](http://files2.genymotion.com/genymotion/genymotion-2.6.0/genymotion-2.6.0.dmg) works though, like the others wrote. But now there are differences between the images, in the download I get 2.7.2 images and no more 2.6.0 images, which gives then warnings and difficutlites as well.

I asked the support and will post here the results if there.

frank

Comment: Weeks later still no answer from the support team of Genymotion.

Comment: Seems to be no support at all at Genymotion. Good to know. But anyway, the performance of Genymotion on Mac OS X is so poor that it is a pain in the glass to use it. I prefer even BlueStacks for just playing Android on Mac. For debugging I do it on a Windows PC.

Comment: Now with Genymotion 2.8.1 the crash doesn't come anymore. But still Genymotion is extremly slow and therefore unusable :(