# pip install -- python 3 -- conda [Illegal instruction: 4]

Tags: python, conda

i'm doing pip install of `scikit-learn` and `nltk` in python 3.6 and get error Illegal instruction: 4. i'm on osx 10.7.5. i had earlier updated python 3 version with conda install python=3

i've re-installed conda, and it looks like a complier error. i'm not fully sure how to de-bug it.

how can i understand what's causing this error? 
how can i fix this?

Answer (score 3):

See this post. [What is the "Illegal Instruction: 4" error and why does "-mmacosx-version-min=10.x" fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268887/what-is-the-illegal-instruction-4-error-and-why-does-mmacosx-version-min-10)

> The "illegal instruction" message is simply telling you that your binaries contain instructions the version of the OS that you are attempting to run them under does not understand. I can't give you the precise meaning of 4 but I expect that is internal to Apple.