# Mac Illegal instruction : 4

Tags: android, c++, xcode, macos, makefile

I am building AOSP(Android Open Source Project) on MAC from [doc](https://source.android.com/source/initializing) and everything works fine although there is some problem which I can google to solve.

When I execute `make`, I got an error:

> Yacc: aidl <= frameworks/base/tools/aidl/aidl_language_y.y
>   
> prebuilts/misc/darwin-x86/bison/bison -d  -o out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl_language_y.cpp frameworks/base/tools/aidl/aidl_language_y.y
>   
> make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl_language_y.cpp] Illegal instruction: 4

**I have googled too much and I tried to install `bison` but it does not work for me.**

Environment:

```
Mac SDK : 10.11
Mac OS  : 10.13
Android : 6.0.1
JDK     : 1.7
XCode   : 8.3
make    : 3.81
```

Can anyone help me ? Thanks in advance.

## UPDATE

I also tried to downgrade `XCode` to 7.3.1 but it does not still work.

## UPDATE for compatibility

`file prebuilts/misc/darwin-x86/bison/bison`
    
output : `prebuilts/misc/darwin-x86/bison/bison: Mach-O executable i386`

`uname -a`
   
 output: `root:xnu-4570.1.46~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64`

Comment: Apparently, something says that `4` is an illegal instruction. Did you look at the `aidl_language_y.cpp` file? Does it look like a C++ parser generated by bison? What happens if you move this file out of the build tree and try to `make` again?

Comment: Do you mean delete the file and make again? @RenaudPacalet

Comment: No, do not delete the file (you never know). Just move it elsewhere and try to make again. If needed, you will move it back.

Comment: I am sorry for some log left and I just updated my question. There is no `aidl_language_y.cpp`.

Comment: OK, what happens if you try to execute `prebuilts/misc/darwin-x86/bison/bison --version`?

Comment: Output is `Illegal instruction: 4`

Comment: The `bison` program is needed to build your project. Unfortunately, the `bison` executable you have was not compiled for your computer architecture. Are you trying to run x86 executables on a PowerPC mac?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156530/discussion-between-lijianixn-and-renaud-pacalet).

Comment: @RenaudPacalet: 4 is just the number for `SIGILL`.

Comment: @DavisHerring You're right, of course. Anyway, the `bison` binary was the responsible: it was apparently damaged.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I have updated my question.

Comment: @visibleman The link is my question.

Comment: lol!, sorry https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268887/what-is-the-illegal-instruction-4-error-and-why-does-mmacosx-version-min-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. The bison executable was broken, so I installed bison with homebrew:

```
brew install bison
```

And then

```
sudo find / -name bison
```

Which gave me the path to the bison installation: /usr/bin/bison I removed the bison file from the AOSP:

```
sudo rm /Volumes/android/prebuilts/misc/darwin-x86/bison/bison
```

(Volumes/android/ is my working directory, the directory with aosp).
Then I created a symbolic link to the bison installed with homebrew:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/bison /Volumes/android/prebuilts/misc/darwin-x86/bison/bison
```

Answer (score 0):

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-building/D1-c5lZ9Oco/V9yPowRdCAAJ

```
cd /Volumes/AOSP/external/bison

git cherry-pick c0c852bd6fe462b148475476d9124fd740eba160
mm

Replace prebuilt bison binary with patched binary

cp /Volumes/AOSP/out/host/darwin-x86/bin/bison /Volumes/AOSP/prebuilts/misc/darwin-x86/bison/
Build
```