# Illegal instruction: 4 on MacOS High Sierra

Tags: python, macos-sierra, illegal-instruction

I am trying to make a chat-looking window in pygame 3.6, I just updated my MacBook to version 10.13.6, before I did this it worked perfectly but after I get the message: Illegal instruction: 4. 

**Code**

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame.gfxdraw

pygame.init()

window_width=360
window_height=640
animation_increment=10
clock_tick_rate=20
size = (window_width, window_height)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
black = (0,0,0)
grey = (220,220,220)
shadow = (0, 255, 0, 100)

pygame.display.set_caption("BrAIn")

dead=False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
background_image = pygame.image.load("background.png").convert()
micro = pygame.image.load("microphone.png")
PF = pygame.image.load("BrAIn.png")


while(dead==False):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            dead = True

    font = pygame.font.Font("Impact copy.ttf", 52)
    text = font.render('BrAIn', True, (0,0,0))

    screen.blit(background_image, [0, 0])
    pygame.gfxdraw.hline(screen, 0, 360, 40, shadow)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, black, [0,62], [360,62], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, grey, [0,30], [360,30], 62)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, grey, [0,620],[360,620],75)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, black, [0,583], [360,583], 2)
    screen.blit(micro, [152, 587])
    screen.blit(PF, [-5, -7])
    screen.blit(text, [125,0])

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(clock_tick_rate)
```

Python 3.6 (and 2.7) also crashes after running this.

Comment: Just to confirm, you are only getting this message with this python script and not others?  Binaries compiled with older versions of MacOS can cause this problem.  See:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268887/what-is-the-illegal-instruction-4-error-and-why-does-mmacosx-version-min-10

Comment: Yeah, it's only with Python, I tried C++, HTML (don't know why I tried that seen that runs on browser), and I tried C. They all worked except for Python 2.7.13 and Python 3.6.7. Also almost every module works exc for pygame. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling it but seen this is a problem with Macintosh I didn't expect it to work.

Comment: I just narrowed the error down, if I remove the `pygame.init()` command, (although it gives me other related errors) it stops giving me the `Illegal instruction: 4` error... Don't know what this means though. And yes, it is only this script (I have no other script that really uses pygame so... I can't really check if it has to do with pygame. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just added some more text and it crashed... Again.

Answer (score 1):

Although "removing pygame.init()" isn't really much of an answer and I would like to know why it does this and how to permanently fix this, I have found a way to 'fix' this problem. I removed the `pygame.init()` command, which gave me the error: `pygame.error: font not initialized`. This is pretty obvious because then you haven't initialized the engine where the fonts are. There is another way without using `pygame.init()` without getting this error (as many of you are aware I think), this is by using `pygame.font.init()`. I tried replacing pygame.init() by pygame.font.init() and finally my program worked like it used to. I would still very much like to know why and how this error is made, how to permanently get rid of it and what difference there is between `pygame.font.init()` and `pygame.init()` but this is a temporary answer for me.

Comment: If you want to, you can report the problem [following these instructions](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/patchesandbugs).

Comment: I just added some more text and it crashed... Again.