# How can I test a MacOS app on a specific version?

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-high-sierra, macos-app-extension

How can I test a MacOS app on a specific version?

I need to start the app on High Sierra and I have Catalina. It does not work as for iPhone simulators

once the app is started, a user receives this in the logs

```
 in  /var/log/messages 

com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] ("bundle"[2956]). Service exited due to signal: illegal instructio: 4 sent by exchandler[0].
```

no problem on Mojave and above

I have searched everywhere but have not found an answer

thanks

Comment: Is your Mac compatible with High Sierra?

Comment: So this is an app extension which crashes, not MacOS app? Also, why do you mention iPhone simulator?

Comment: @Willeke yes but I can't find anywhere to download high sierra to install the image with parallels

Answer (score -1):

From the [Apple Developer Forum](https://devforums.apple.com/message/773142):

> The compiler and linker are capable of using features and performing
>   optimizations that do not work on older OS versions.
>   -mmacosx-version-min tells the tools what OS versions you need to work with, so the tools can disable optimizations that won't run on those
>   OS versions. If you need to run on older OS versions then you must use
>   this flag.
>
> "The downside to -mmacosx-version-min is that the app's performance
>   may be worse on newer OS versions then it could have been if it did
>   not need to be backwards-compatible. In most cases the differences are
>   small.

**The place to put this flag is under “Other Linker Flags” in the project’s build settings, e.g. -mmacosx-version-min=10.10.**

from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14285922/10032726)

Comment: Note: Not an answer to "How can I test a MacOS app on a specific version?".

Comment: @Willeke I've added -mmacosx-version-min=10.12. But now How can I test on my Mac? I have Catalina, but I need to test on High Sierra 10.13.6 version

Comment: @Willeke o gargo