# Illegal instruction: 4 while installing passport package in laravel

Tags: laravel, macos

I have a project  created in reactjs as frontend and laravel as backend, I have used two packages for authentication in backend I have used Jetstream package and in frontend I need to user Passport package, now when a run `php artisan passport:install` it when I get this error `Illegal instruction: 4`  I have tried to find different resource but I have not get any working. Please any help on how to fix this. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the "Illegal Instruction: 4" error and why does "-mmacosx-version-min=10.x" fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268887/what-is-the-illegal-instruction-4-error-and-why-does-mmacosx-version-min-10)

Comment: I have read this article but what exactly have to do to solve this error

Comment: depends on your installation, as you can see the error is more about you using macos than laravel. As how to fix your issue ? i dont know, you shared no details of your installation.

Comment: Therefore this problem is associated with mac OS right?

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try removing the passport package & reinstalling it?

```
composer remove laravel/passport
composer require laravel/passport
```

You could also try:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: On a way to solve this problem I downloaded a fresh laravel project but when I do install the passport package I still get the some error

Comment: One temporary workaround would be to raise the stack limit of the php process using ulimit(1) and run your command again in the same Terminal window: ulimit -s 65532